# Enzyme mount rendering multiple components when only one exists

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having a bit of a challenge wrapping my head around why enzyme's mount is rendering multiple elements when only one exists.

I have a snackbar from Material UI with a data-test-id shown below:

```
         <MySnackbar
                open={true}
                variant="error"
                message={"Test message"}
                onClose={this.handleRequestClose}
                data-test-id="snackbar_isErrorWhileCheckingUpdates"
            />
```

I tested this as shown below:

```
it("Should render notification snackbars for information", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={mockStore(initialState)}>
        <Updates.WrappedComponent location={location} history={history} match={match} {...props} path={path}/>
    </Provider>;

        expect(wrapper.find('[data-test-id="snackbar_isErrorWhileCheckingUpdates"]')).toHaveLength(1);
    })
```

The above test fails because it finds 2 elements.
When I use `hostNodes()` it returns 0 elements.

I'm wondering what happens and enzyme renders multiple components.

**EDIT**
Below are the contents of when `debug()` is called

```
 <WithStyles(MySnackbar) open={false} variant="error" message="There was a network problem whilst checking for updates" onClose={[Function]} data-test-id="snackbar_isErrorWhileCheckingUpdates">
  <MySnackbar classes={{...}} open={false} variant="error" message="There was a network problem whilst checking for updates" onClose={[Function]} data-test-id="snackbar_isErrorWhileCheckingUpdates">
    <WithStyles(ForwardRef(Snackbar)) open={false} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={[Function]} message={{...}} action={{...}}>
      <ForwardRef(Snackbar) classes={{...}} open={false} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={[Function]} message={{...}} action={{...}} />
    </WithStyles(ForwardRef(Snackbar))>
  </MySnackbar>
</WithStyles(MySnackbar)>


<MySnackbar classes={{...}} open={false} variant="error" message="There was a network problem whilst checking for updates" onClose={[Function]} data-test-id="snackbar_isErrorWhileCheckingUpdates">
  <WithStyles(ForwardRef(Snackbar)) open={false} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={[Function]} message={{...}} action={{...}}>
    <ForwardRef(Snackbar) classes={{...}} open={false} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={[Function]} message={{...}} action={{...}} />
  </WithStyles(ForwardRef(Snackbar))>
</MySnackbar>
```

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log` the [debug](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html) output?

Comment: Hello. I've added an edit to show the console.log output

Comment: I'm curious why there are two trees displayed from your debug output. Is this output from a single debug call?

Comment: Yes they are from a single debug call

Comment: Then the `MySnackbar` component is being rendered twice, right?

Comment: Exactly. Im trying to understand how enzymes mount comprehends the material UI components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue described is known [here](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/836) and the solution is [there](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/836#issuecomment-401260477) as well. In my case ***hostNodes*** helped me.

Do similar to :

```
wrapper.find('#yourSelector').hostNodes().text();
```